Can some dry run for nQueens problem all ways?
public static void Queens(char b[][],int row) {
        if(row==b.length){
            print(b);
            return;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<b[0].length;j++){
            b[row][j]='Q';
            Queens(b,row+1);
            b[row][j]='x';
        }

    }
   main(){
    Queens(b,0);}

this is my current code and i am unable to dry run with backtracking so if someone would help me
I tried dry running many time but can understand upto
Q x
Q x
and
Q x
x Q
not further to it
i am unable to understand how will these two output will be printed
x Q
Q x
x Q
x Q

What do you mean by "dry running" exactly? I'm not clear what "I tried dry running many time but can understand upto Q x Q x and Q x x Q not further to it i am unable to understand how will these two output will be printed x Q" means.

@ggorlen I believe he means the drawing of queens (Qs) on a grid. He is marking where they are (or where they are not?) or something similar with xs on said grid. There is some recursion in his code, but I agree, the code is without context and his question is vague (to put it mildly).
